# 'MASS::predict.lda' is not an exported object from 'namespace:MASS'

Tags: r, namespaces, lda, cran, mass

This `R` code:

```
Iris <- data.frame(rbind(iris3[,,1], iris3[,,2], iris3[,,3]),
                   Sp = rep(c("s","c","v"), rep(50,3)))
train <- sample(1:150, 75)
z <- MASS::lda(Sp ~ ., Iris, prior = c(1,1,1)/3, subset = train)
MASS::predict.lda(z)
```

gives the following error message:

```
Error: 'predict.lda' is not an exported object from 'namespace:MASS'
```

The `predict.lda` function of `MASS` is documented but, apparently, not part of the package's namespace. Why not?

This problem is important because I need to use `predict.lda` in a package of my own and this error is making it fail the CRAN checks.

Comment: Maybe in some past version of MASS, actual version does not have `predict.lda`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can load the package and then use `predict`

```
library(MASS)
predict(z)
```

---

Or specify the `:::`.  According to `?":::"`

> Accessing exported and internal variables, i.e. R objects (including lazy loaded data sets) in a namespace.

```
MASS:::predict.lda(z)
#$class
# [1] v s s s s c s v s v v v v c v v c v c s s s s c c v c v v c s s v c s s c v s c v v s c s c s c c s v c s s c s s c c c s c s v
#[65] v v v s c s c v v s s
#Levels: c s v

#$posterior
#               c            s            v
#107 3.513603e-03 1.352029e-37 9.964864e-01
#37  2.749629e-26 1.000000e+00 5.088976e-50
# ...
```

---

Or another option is to get the function from name space

```
predictlda <- getFromNamespace("predict.lda", "MASS")
predictlda(z)
#$class
# [1] v s s s s c s v s v v v v c v v c v c s s s s c c v c v v c s s v c s s c v s c v v s c s c s c c s v c s s c s s c c c s c s v
#[65] v v v s c s c v v s s
#Levels: c s v

#$posterior
#               c            s            v
#107 3.513603e-03 1.352029e-37 9.964864e-01
#37  2.749629e-26 1.000000e+00 5.088976e-50
# ..
```

Comment: Using `:::` in a package is discouraged and gives the following warning message in CRAN checks: `Unexported objects imported by ':::' calls:
  ‘MASS:::predict.lda’ ‘MASS:::predict.qda’
  See the note in ?::: about the use of this operator.`

Comment: It does. Thanks!